# Why does Java ask me to hit Enter again?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been racking my brain for a while trying to understand how Scanner works. So here's the code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine();
String p = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(p);
System.out.println(sc.hasNextLine());
```

What I **expect**:

```
Love is good  <- press ENTER
Love is blind <- press ENTER
Love is good  <- output
Love is blind <- output
false
```

What I **have**:

```
Love is good   <- I press ENTER
Love is blind  <- I press ENTER
Love is good   <- output
Love is blind  <- output
<- press ENTER
true <- output
```

What I **do not understand**:

1. Instead of immediate printing this line - System.out.println(sc.hasNextLine()); - it makes me to press ENTER again
2. It prints true instead of false while there no more lines or symbols

What I **have read**: I *have* read a dozen of stackoverflow answers about using hasNextLine() after nextInt() and about how nextInt() does not consume the final symbol in the line but I don't understand why, even though I don't use nextInt() in here, I still need to press ENTER one more time and why hasNextLine() is true.

Comment: It is easy to construct an example where there would be no next line: write the input into a text file, then pipe that text file into the java program via the command line. Since the end of the input would be reached, your program would output false. It is also possible to end the input in a manual session, on my Bash this works with Ctrl+D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `Scanner` use `BufferedReader` like so:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String s = reader.readLine();
        String p = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(p);      
        System.out.println(reader.ready());
    }
}
```

For more reading into the matter, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637032/bufferedreader-vs-console-vs-scanner). As a rule of thumb, when you need parsing stuff (like `nextInt`) use `Scanner`, otherwise stick to `BufferedReader`. BufferedReader is a lot faster than `Scanner` too.

#### As for why you got that *troublesome* behavior, see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for `Scanner`.

The part that applies in your particular case is:

> A scanning operation may block waiting for input.

What this means in your case is: after the first two lines are read by `Scanner`, the `Scanner` was waiting for input, caused by its method call `sc.hasNextLine()`. Then when <kbd>Enter</kbd> was hit, it got an input (hence it prints `true`, according to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--) it returns `true` when there is input). As after the method call `sc.hasNextLine()` there are no more executable lines in your program, the program ends, giving the illusion that it required *two* enter hits.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Never used that before! I'm asking that all to solve problems on UVa Online Judge and using BufferReader + parsing seems easier than using Scanner. Thank you.

Comment: Done it, thanks. It also seems a lot easier with no nextInt()-nextLine() issues.

Comment: but does this answer the original question?

Comment: @Jasper Can you please tell me how the original question is not answered here, so that I can edit if I have to?

Answer (score 11):

From the [Scanner documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (emphasis by me):

```
public boolean hasNextLine()
```

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner. ***This method may block while waiting for input***. The scanner does not advance past any input.

What's probably happening is that `hasNextLine` is blocking because it's waiting for input, which you give by pressing enter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you also please tell me how to fix that presuming that I need to use Scanner?

Answer (score 10):

First of all you are using Scanner declared to System.in so this means you are asking .in to check if their is any more value so it waits for the user to input something and after you press enter it is obvious that it returns true.

So if you want to check s or p declare Scanner like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
```

or

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(p);
```

then check for `sc.hasNextLine();` this should return false as much I know but for user input I would recommend to create another Scanner variable and then take values from the user and use sc for your `hasNextline()` thing.

I hope the very first logic helps you.

Comment: You are scanning the lines already read? Use System.in instead of s and p.

Comment: But Brother that is the reason he is getting true as a answer when he wants to check is their is any more line and with System.in it is going to return true every time.

Answer (score 9):

**You are *asking* for three lines of input!**

Standard input *always* has one more line coming until you *close the terminal*. On a Unix system, you can probably press Ctrl+D at the end, and it will return `flase` (= input closed).

The program would behave as expected if you had a *finite* input. But interactive input: **how does the program know the user does not intend to input Shakespeare next**?

The function `hasNextLine()` will **wait for new input to arrive** (or for the signal that there cannot be new input). This function is not for "did the user *already* input another line" but instead means "*wait* for the next line". So for practical purposes, `hasNextLine()` is equivalent to "is the user input still connected, and *could* it eventually contain another line".

Why do you need that last line? Just *remove* it!

Comment: I see you point :) The last line was for understanding how hasNextLine() works. As I've written above, I've started solving problems on UVa Online Judge and the grader is sooo picky about how you organise the input loop so I have to understand how input in Java works (I'm way too bad at C++ to do problem solving).

Comment: When the input comes from a file, you *can* expect `hasNextLine` to eventually be false (but you don't want to use this API it is too slow for this contest). Still, you may or may not have an extra line at the end.

Answer (score 6):

You have the problem, that the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is reading from the given [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) which can be something like a file or in your case [System.in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in).

As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16874004/5450645) a File has an end and the `sc.hasNextLine()` will return false. 
By using the stream you expect it not to have an end to be able to provide input data and therefore will block and wait for your next input.

Maybe you can think of some "exiting char" (here it is the '#'):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (line.equals("#")) {
        break;
    }
    builder.append(line + "\n");
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I debugged your example and saw that

```
System.out.println(sc.hasNextLine());
```

line waits for a new input. It is neither true nor false. It does not exist. That is why, it blocks the application. It does not matter what you entered (enter or any other button on the keyboard), it would give you true because you supplied a new input.

Comment: It's not "null" because that would print as `null`. It has not yet returned

Comment: Yes, I know. Probably, there is a bigger problem than being a null. I just wanted to share the value of this line, when it blocks.

Comment: The "value of this line" also is not `null`, but it does not exist. (A primitive `boolean` *cannot* be `null`, only object variables can be `null` pointers)

Comment: It's still incorrect. It does matter which keys are pressed. For example if you typed "abc" and then closed the pioe (e.g. via Ctrl+D in a unix terminal) it would return `false `.