# What is difference between console.readLine() and Scanner?

Tags: java

My teacher is using `Console.ReadLine()`, but I've learned to use `Scanner`.

```
int age = console.readLine("age: ");
```

and

```
System.out.println("age: ");
int age = scan.nextInt();
```

1. What is the difference between these?
2. Is it possible to write scan method in one line like `readLine`?
3. How can I use console on IDES?

Comment: Read the documentation.  `readLine()` doesn't return `int`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637032/bufferedreader-vs-console-vs-scanner