# When using a Java Scanner, is there ever a need to wrap the InputStream argument into an InputStreamReader? And then into a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, java-io, inputstreamreader

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637032/bufferedreader-vs-console-vs-scanner) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader?rq=1) Q&A's, given that Java's Scanner supports both character encoding as well as buffering, is there ever a need to wrap the `InputStream` into a `InputStreamReader`, before passing it into the Scanner? If so, is there ever a need to wrap the `InputStreamReader` into a `BuffereedReader` first?

In other words, is there ever a scenario where the following code is *not* redundant.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedStreamReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bufferedStreamReader);
```

I am learning Java (from Python), and am trying to better understand the similarities, differences, and use cases for all the various IO classes.

(Edit1): I know that we could replace the first two lines with a single line using `FileReader` - but that's what the `FileReader` itself would do internally, so the purpose of the example (and this question) is to understand the underlying relationship of the different IO classes - hence the explicit call to `FileInputStream` use.

(Edit2): [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) Java tutorial actually does this wrapping.

Comment: It wraps an `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader` itself, but you will benefit from using `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a moot point; you rarely want scanner (it doesn't really do what you think it does. It does what its spec says it does, but, read it. It's *weird* - it's not particularly suitable for, well, anything, really). And you don't need this code - this is the old file API. There's a new one:

```
Path p = Path.of("/path/to/some/dir/someFileInDir.txt");
p = p.getParent().resolve("someOtherFile.txt");

try (var in = Files.newBufferedReader(p)) {
  while (true) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;
  }
}
```

You can one-liner it with `Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of("/path/to/file.txt"))`, of course.

For what its worth:

- `FileInputStream` does not buffer. If you call `.read()` (i.e. the 'read 1 byte please' method), it will ask the underlying OS for just one byte. On modern SSDs, that means the OS will read the entire block, then toss everything out except that 1 byte you want. Yes, you should wrap them in buffers if you or any code you use has any intention of calling `.read()`, but if you're just going to call `.read(byte[])` with a byte array that's large enough (4096 or so is plenty, let alone more), there's no need for that.
- `InputStreamReader` also doesn't.
- `Scanner` **does**, by default 1024.

So, the answer is: That code you found is *mostly* useless, but 1024 is a bit low. BufferedInputStream defaults to 8192 instead which is a better number. Still, 1024 gets you ~1024x better performance vs. asking for single bytes from a non-buffered block-based source. Assuming those blocks are 8192 bytes long, Scanner is only ~8x slower without that intermediate buffer. And that's assuming 100% of the bottleneck is the 'read from disk' part. Which it might be, disks are slow.

That's all relevant *if* you are handrolling your buffered stack which you shouldn't (use `Files.newBufferedX` - check the API, there's lots there, generally you can just make what you need in one go, though you can't make scanners in one go), and using `Scanner` which you shouldn't.

Comment: Well, I actually wrote  a basic timing test - comparing the 4-line version above of Scanner (with buffered intermediary) with a Scanner that simply reading from InputStream (middle 2 lines removed) - and the *latter* (surprisingly) always comes out 1-2 times faster. I tested both Scanners reading from a text file (using forEachRemaining) with up to 500,000 lines long....

Comment: We'd need to know a ton of details to know if that's a fair analysis. There's hotspot warmup (you didn't hang this in a [JMH](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness) harness, did you? If not, pretty much all microbenchmarking is suspect), and, of course, hardware. If you have a very slow CPU and very fast SSDs, it's _possible_ the pointless second buffer slows things down, but, it's _unlikely_ to say the least. If you want to dig deeper, post a new question and include the _entire_ test code, self-contained.

Comment: Preferably with code that _produces_ a 500k random textfile: Make it truly self contained. It's somewhat likely folks on different hardware get wildly different results.